# How to allow Visual Studio to upgrade the project automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have some compatibility problems with vs 2010 file opened in vs 2013, i have read that maybe i can solve it activating the option "upgrade project automaticcaly" but i can't find it. Where i can find this option in Visual Studio 2013 Express?

EDIT

I can't launch the project ,i have tried in VS2010 Express , VS2012 Express , VS2013 Express... It seems so strange, it's an official demo of kinect sdk.

EDIT

Suddenly it starts work on visual studio 2010

Comment: When you open a older version VS project in a newer version is will do the upgrade - but that is at a project level - not a "coding" level. What is your specific issue?

Comment: I'm trying to open the kinect demo xna-avateering for kinect official sdk... Un solution explorer menu my project won't open the messaga is something like "the project is not compatible with this version of visual studio"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a project upgrade issue but the sounds of that error message - VS2013 Express doesn't support the project type you are trying to open.

The following page describes the s/w requirements for use that project

[Kinect or Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855359.aspx#Software_Requirements)

Specifically the s/w dev requirements are:

- Visual Studio 2010, or Visual Studio 2012. The free Express editions can be downloaded from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express or Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express.
- .NET Framework 4 (installed with Visual Studio 2010), or .NET Framework 4.5 (installed with Visual Studio 2012).

There are a lot of other requirements also listed on that page.

I would suggest you download VS2012 Express (its free) and work from there.

Comment: ok i will try but you think that install visual studio 2010 in a machine with visual studio 2013 already installed can cause some issue?

Comment: I know of no reason why you can't run VS2010 and VS2013 side by side on the same machine.

Comment: thanks but i can't find a version c# of vs2012 express in microsoft site, only 2013 and 2010... The 2010 version cause the same error...

Comment: found it, i'll try with vs2012 ,i open the original project with notepad and i see that it was created with vs2012.